# Relationship laravel : count data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Model `Category`:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(products::class);
}
```

Model `product`:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

I handle in controller:

```
$result = Category::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->with(['product:category_id, status'])
    ->where('order', 1)
    ->get();
```

Result when I print out raw data :

```
[
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'Hot'
  'product' => [
     'status' => 1,
     'category_id' => 1
   ]
]
[
   'id' => 2,
   'name' => 'New'
   'product' => [
      'status' => 2,
      'category_id' => 2
   ]
]
..........
```

I got the list of category `id` and `name`, and got the product data array based on relationship. In my product table, There is a `status` column with values ​​equal to 1,2,3.

**Now I want to count how many status = 1 and how many status = [2, 3] through the product array I get using that relationship?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) for counting related data. lets say, you want total products, status1 products and status23 products.

```
$result = Category::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->with(['product:category_id, status'])
    ->withCount([
        'product', 
        'product as status_one_product' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
         },
         'product as status_other_product' => function ($query) {
              $query->whereIn('status', [2, 3]);
          }
     ])
     ->where('order', 1)
     ->get();
```

now you can get counted data like

```
echo $result[0]->product_count; // total product
echo $result[0]->status_one_product; // total product with status 1
echo $result[0]->status_other_product; // total product with status 2 and 3
```

Comment: Thank you. You tell me, my data is about 200,000 items but counting it takes 10 seconds. Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: apaik there's nothing more you can do to improve the performance in this code.

Comment: So is there any other way to make it faster?

Comment: If the status of products don't change often, you could cache the products status count and update through an event. The answer of Zahid results in a complex sql request.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey Yes, my status doesn't change often.Can you reply with code for me..Thank you very much

Comment: @destrils if you want to count using query, there's no other way i guess. a possible workaround would be add a json column in your category and keep product counts in it. when you are adding or editing a product update the count in category accordingly.

Comment: The 2nd solution of @zahidhasanemon is db based, not very practical as you would have to update 20K records. What I did in a similar scenario is create an event and trigger the event when a product status changes and send it to the queue worker. Save the results in the Laravel Cache as a flat array or 2 separate keys and pull it out when needed. I can't write that code as I don't know enough of your app. This is the idea anyway. Good luck! Maybe mark Zahid's answer as correct but not practical in your case because of 20K records.